# Have Steve Rogers (Captain America) and a young Erik Lehnsherr (Magneto) interacted during WWII?

Tags: marvel, comics, captain-america, magneto

Captain America served in World War II and Magneto's backstory revolves around his time in a concentration camp.

Have Steve Rogers and a young Erik Lehnsherr interacted during WWII?

Presumably this would have to be in the comics since the MCU and XCU have been distinct (for now).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Twice in comics, once in cartoon; but not in the "main" set of events.

Have Cap and Magneto met? Yes and no. *(occurences are ordered by date of publication)*

Yes, because in *What if?* #28 (1991), Captain America and fellow soldiers encounter a young "Magnus" in a concentration camp. No, because... it's a *What if?*, so the story isn't exactly canon, and in that timeline, "Magnus" never became Magneto, thanks to the life lesson Cap gave him about not dividing people based on their differences.

[image: Captain America rescues a concentration camp]

*X-Men: Evolution* season 2, episode 11 had a different take on that, with Cap (and Wolverine) rescuing Magneto, but presumably no time for the life lesson; hence, him becoming who he was in the TV show.

*X-Men: Grand Design* #1 (2017) has a Watcher recording some events about "a pantheon of mutants". We see an alternate Earth where, possibly influenced by the
*Evolution* line-up, Wolverine and Captain America are on a cover mission, and witness a kid being beaten up. Kid turns out to be Magneto, and he uses his powers on Cap's shield to get rid of his bullies.

[image: Young Magneto uses Cap's shield on German soldiers]

Comment: The Bop sound effects make it seem like they're just being casually knocked out, but the top left Nazi looks like he's just getting sliced in half.

Comment: Darn shame on the first one, would have liked to see all the comics where Magneto is a hero...

Answer (score 8):

In the *What if? Volume 2* #28 comic "What if Captain America had led an army of Super Soldiers in WWII? Steve meets and frees a young Magneto at Auschwitz.

[image]

Also in the cartoon *X-Men: Evolution* Captain America and Wolverine free Magneto from a concentration camp.